# Mac: How to change my DNS to load American sites faster?

Tags: networking, dns

I am in Korea right now and I need to go on google.com / google.co.kr to search for programming related stuff. However, google pages load slow as hell when I am at home.

I tested my internet speed and it's at ~65 mbps (download), so I suspect that it is the DNS. When I go on naver.com (Korea's google), it loads super fast.

Is there any way I can change the DNS so that I can load American sites faster?

P.S. I use a Macbook.

Comment: Google is not (only) hosted in the US. So your problem isn’t that. DNS is also only involved with very few connections. There’s plenty of caching.

Comment: You can check DNS speed yourself, try `nslookup google.com` in the command prompt. For me the response is almost instant. Remember that it's not just your internet connection's speed that matters, there's no direct connection between your computer and Google's servers, your request and their response pass through a bunch of intermediate devices. Every single one of them affects the connection speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to how to change your DNS. I'm not sure a DNS will change how fast a page loads but I mean you can always try and see if you experience some performance increases.

> How to change my DNS

1. Go to the Apple menu and select "System Preferences"
2. Click on “Network”
3. select your network interface from the left side (“Wi-Fi” or
   “Ethernet” for example)
4. Then click the “Advanced” button in the lower right corner of the
   Network window
5. Choose the “DNS” tab at the top of the screen
6. To add a new DNS server: click on the [+] plus button

When finished making changes to the DNS settings, click on the "OK" button
Now click on "Apply" for the DNS changes to take effect, close out of System Preferences as usual. [source](http://osxdaily.com/2015/12/05/change-dns-server-settings-mac-os-x/)

> to load American sites faster?

I'm not sure if a DNS is going to load American pages faster. You would need to get an IP address from a dns server that is close to you or america. Here are some DNS ip addresses that i got from this site http://www.bestdns.org/

OpenDNS 208.67.222.222  208.67.220.220  San Antonio, Texas, USA

Level3  209.244.0.3 209.244.0.4 Diamond Bar, California, USA

DNS Advantage   156.154.70.1    156.154.71.1    Sterling, Virginia, USA

Google  8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

Comment: Looks like changing it to 208.67.222.222 (OpenDNS) worked!! Not sure if it's just a temporary thing... we'll see